# XSLT to map multiple source nodes to same target node

Tags: xslt

We have a collection of orders that come as single XML. One of the lines is mandatory and is called the main line and it is only one per order and is at the header level without any repetition. There are two other line types which are not mandatory but can repeat for each order. Following is the input XML sample and the output is just a collection of lines.

All the lines including main line, all Optional lines and all custom lines need to be mapped to the same element on the target per each order.

```
    <orderDetails>
   <data>
      <order>
         <poNumber>1234</poNumber>
         <storeNumber>35</storeNumber>
         <itemNumber>1895550045</itemNumber>
         <mainLine>
            <referenceNumber>I1</referenceNumber>
            <basicInstallCostAmount>100</basicInstallCostAmount>
            <basicInstallQuantity>12</basicInstallQuantity>
         </mainLine>
         <optionalLines>
            <optionalLine>
               <referenceNumber>OP10</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>15</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>200</orderRetailAmount>
            </optionalLine>
            <optionalLine>
               <referenceNumber>OP105</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>23</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>655</orderRetailAmount>
            </optionalLine>
         </optionalLines>
         <customLines>
            <customLine>
               <referenceNumber>C100</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>123</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>12300</orderRetailAmount>
            </customLine>
            <customLine>
               <referenceNumber>C1337</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>357</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>143</orderRetailAmount>
            </customLine>
         </customLines>
      </order>
      <order>
         <poNumber>5678</poNumber>
         <storeNumber>52</storeNumber>
         <itemNumber>0005554433</itemNumber>
         <mainLine>
            <referenceNumber>I21</referenceNumber>
            <basicInstallCostAmount>3000</basicInstallCostAmount>
            <basicInstallQuantity>35</basicInstallQuantity>
         </mainLine>
         <optionalLines>
            <optionalLine>
               <referenceNumber>OP134</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>1500</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>350000</orderRetailAmount>
            </optionalLine>
         </optionalLines>
         <customLines>
            <customLine>
               <referenceNumber>C140</referenceNumber>
               <duoiCode>EA</duoiCode>
               <orderQuantity>13</orderQuantity>
               <orderRetailAmount>100</orderRetailAmount>
            </customLine>
         </customLines>
      </order>
   </data>
</orderDetails>
```

Expected output -

```
<PoHeadersCollection>
   <PoHeaders>
      <poNumber>1234</poNumber>
      <storeNumber>35</storeNumber>
      <itemNumber>1895550045</itemNumber>
      <PoLinesCollection>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>I1</partNumber>
            <Quantity>12</Quantity>
            <installType>Basic</installType>
            <lineAmount>100</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>OP10</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>15</Quantity>
            <installType>Optional</installType>
            <lineAmount>200</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>OP105</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>23</Quantity>
            <installType>Optional</installType>
            <lineAmount>655</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>C100</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>123</Quantity>
            <installType>Custom</installType>
            <lineAmount>12300</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>C1337</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>357</Quantity>
            <installType>Custom</installType>
            <lineAmount>143</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
      </PoLinesCollection>
   </PoHeaders>
   <PoHeaders>
      <poNumber>5678</poNumber>
      <storeNumber>52</storeNumber>
      <itemNumber>0005554433</itemNumber>
      <PoLinesCollection>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>I21</partNumber>
            <Quantity>35</Quantity>
            <installType>Basic</installType>
            <lineAmount>3000</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>OP134</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>1500</Quantity>
            <installType>Optional</installType>
            <lineAmount>350000</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
         <PoLines>
            <partNumber>C140</partNumber>
            <Uom>EA</Uom>
            <Quantity>13</Quantity>
            <installType>Custom</installType>
            <lineAmount>100</lineAmount>
         </PoLines>
      </PoLinesCollection>
   </PoHeaders>
</PoHeadersCollection>
```

I tried using a for-each and within the loop tried to apply template for the rest of the line types but it is repeating all the nodes.

Below is the XSLT I tried to use and missing on how to apply templates for the current node alone inside the for loop -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PoHeadersCollection>
      <xsl:for-each select="/orderDetails/data/order">
        <ThdIconxPoHeaders>
          <poNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="poNumber"/>
          </poNumber>
          <storeNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="storeNumber"/>
          </storeNumber>
          <itemNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="itemNumber"/>
          </itemNumber>
          <PoLinesCollection>
            <PoLines>
              <partNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="mainLine/referenceNumber"/>
              </partNumber>
              <Uom>
                <xsl:value-of select="mainLine/duoiCode"/>
              </Uom>
              <Quantity>
                <xsl:value-of select="mainLine/basicInstallQuantity"/>
              </Quantity>
              <installType>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">Basic</xsl:text>
              </installType>
              <lineAmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="mainLine/basicInstallCostAmount"/>
              </lineAmount>
            </PoLines>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='optionalLine']"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='customLine']"/>
          </PoLinesCollection>
        </PoHeaders>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </PoHeadersCollection>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='optionalLine']">
    <PoLines>
      <partNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="referenceNumber"/>
      </partNumber>
      <Uom>
        <xsl:value-of select="duoiCode"/>
      </Uom>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="orderQuantity"/>
      </Quantity>
      <installType>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">Optional</xsl:text>
      </installType>
    </PoLines>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='customLine']">
    <PoLines>
      <partNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="referenceNumber"/>
      </partNumber>
      <Uom>
        <xsl:value-of select="duoiCode"/>
      </Uom>
      <Quantity>
        <xsl:value-of select="orderQuantity"/>
      </Quantity>
      <installType>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">Custom</xsl:text>
      </installType>
    </PoLines>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please Suggest.

Thanks in advance,
Geeta

Comment: Show yyour xslt please

Comment: Hello Jim, I did add the XSLT I have been using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the absolute paths such as

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[local-name()='optionalLine']"/>
```

which will select all lines of the appropriate type from *every* order in the document every time. Instead you need to use *relative* paths without a leading slash

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="optionalLines/optionalLine"/>
```

to find just those lines that are inside the order you're currently looking at.

Personally I would break down the big monolithic block into smaller templates to capture the commonality between the different types of lines.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <PoHeadersCollection>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="orderDetails/data/order" />
  </PoHeadersCollection>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
  <PoHeaders>
    <xsl:copy-of select="poNumber | storeNumber | itemNumber" />
    <PoLinesCollection>
      <!-- process all the different types of line in one go -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="mainLine
                    | optionalLines/optionalLine
                    | customLines/customLine" />
    </PoLinesCollection>
  </PoHeaders>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mainLine | optionalLine | customLine">
  <PoLines>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="referenceNumber"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="duoiCode"/><!-- won't exist for main line -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="basicInstallQuantity | orderQuantity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="lineType" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="basicInstallCostAmount | orderRetailAmount"/>
  </PoLines>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="referenceNumber">
  <partNumber><xsl:apply-templates/></partNumber>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="duoiCode">
  <Uom><xsl:apply-templates/></Uom>
</xsl:template>

<!-- etc. for other elements -->
```

and use a special template *mode* to handle the `installType`:

```
<xsl:template match="mainLine" mode="lineType">
  <installType>Basic</installType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="optionalLine" mode="lineType">
  <installType>Optional</installType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customLine" mode="lineType">
  <installType>Custom</installType>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank You Ian,                                                     I did edit the question to include the XSLT I have been using. The actual XML has almost 10 such repeating nodes and each node will have around 50 elements. Also half of these elements are not common between repeating nodes.

Comment: @user3352765 I've edited to explain why you're getting the repetition with your current stylesheet, but I'd still recommend breaking it down into smaller more reusable parts where this makes sense. If you decide you want `quantity` instead of `Quantity` in the output then there's only one template to modify rather than 3.

Comment: Thank You Ian! Relative XPATH did fix the issue. I will break it into reusable parts as per your recommendation. Thank You for all the help!!!